# Request.getCurrent().getRequestId() returns null

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I implemented one feature where either a case is created from chat, api, UI, or Email, I am trying to get `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()`. I tried creating an case from email but `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()`  is returning null to me.

I thought it will return the unique identifier for whole synchronous transaction from wherever i used (i can use `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()`  in multiple classes so ideally it should return same identifier as they are running as part of one transaction). I am using email services.

The email services is inserting case. I am using this function in both case trigger handler and email handler class.

Comment: where are you calling `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()`?  Use [edit] to amend your post

Comment: I amended but does that really matter when you have email services class working ?

Comment: so you are not using email-to-case but instead are using apex inbound email services to create cases?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We are using NLP API when the email is received to create a case, so implemented email services

Comment: I reproduced this, Quiddity is `INBOUND_EMAIL_SERVICE` but RequestId is `NULL` . You should file a support case - if you don't have premier support, I'm happy to do so as I'm curious about this as well

Comment: You can file it as I dont have premier support yet :)

Comment: filed; don't expect a response for a few days and likely to be either Known Issue or Working as designed

Comment: Yes, i used old technique for generating UUID as of now

Comment: the requestId is designed to work with what is emitted in Event Logs (so one's custom logging can be correlated with SFDC eventLogs)

Comment: yes i know, i just needed a unique pattern which can be used to find out that its one sync  transaction running..so as of now using UUID but it would have been better if  Request.getCurrent().getRequestId() would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been logged as a bug (W-13866259) in Salesforce on August 1, 2023

You can [read the thread](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007BG9z6SAD) that includes a response by the Product Manager

> Chris Peterson (Salesforce)
>
> I was able to reproduce this, and confirm the underling internal logs also have a null requestId. This might actually be the proper behavior but I opened a bug (W-13866259) to look into it and either update the documentation or fix.